# Remove 4 character before each comma in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, mysql, regex

I have the following text in my NotePad++ file

```
H3J 2J6,H3J 2J7,H3J 2Z8,H3J 2T8
```

(there is actually 100s of lines in this format), how do I remove the first 4 characters (including the space) so it's displayed as

```
'H3J', 'H3J', 'H3J', 'H3J',
```

The idea is to parse the text and have it ready to `INSERT INTO` a database afterwards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you already know, but for a full answer, you can do this using regex and the find and replace dialog.

Find: `.{3}\s(.{3})`

Replace With: `\'$1\'`

Search Mode: Regular Expression

`.{3}\s` Matches 3 chars then a space `(.{3})` matches the next three chars and captures as a group.

`\'$1\'` Replaces the text that was found in the above statement with the group we captured adding quotes around it. Leaving any commas as they originally were.

With regex there are many ways to do this, this is just one example.

[image: Regex]

**Edit:**

From your comment I believe you wanted the the first item from the first group, and the second item from any following three groups.

The regex for that would be:

Find: `(.{3})\s.{3},.{3}\s(.{3}),.{3}\s(.{3}),.{3}\s(.{3})`

Replace With: `\'$1\',\'$2\',\'$3\',\'$4\',`

If you want to get the first group like your example now reads. Use the following regex:

Find: `(.{3})\s(.{3})`

Replace: `\'$1\'`

and finally to add commas to the end of every line, use this:

Find: `$`

Replace: `,`

Comment: Great answer mt025, thank you for the detailed response. The regex seems to discard the first 3 characters and keep the last 3 characters, is there a way to keep the first 3 characters instead?

Comment: I'm a little confused with the question? So you want the the first item from the first group, and the second item from any following groups?

Comment: I have added that to the answer anyway. Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: mt025 you're right, I apologise as my original question was off. I have edited the question now, I actually need the first 3 characters of each group. I'm going to mark your answer anyways since it answers the original question.

Comment: Ah okay, I ill change my original answer to reflect that.

Comment: Edited, let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: mt025 can I ask for one last favor please? how would I go from `'H2J','H3N','H3N','H2J','H2P','H2K','H2J','H2K','H3N'` to `(H2J),(H3N),(H3N),(H2J),(H2P),(H2K),(H2J),(H2K),(H3N)` ? Is there a cheat sheet I can use for the regex somewhere so as to learn the basics?

Comment: This is a good site: http://www.regextester.com/. You can test and it has a cheat sheet on the right hand side.

Comment: Find: `'(.{3})'` Replace: `\($1\)`

Comment: Thanks mt, that site is really good and helped me to make further edits.